# How to increase canvas size by a fixed number of pixels in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions, canvas

How can I create an action that increases the canvas size by a specified number of pixels?

I want to batch process a number of files of unknown size to add a consistent white border around each one, without affecting the scaling/cropping of the original picture. In other words, if the original picture is 200px x 350px I would like to automatically increase the canvas to 300px x 450px, leaving the image centered inside a 50px border.

I know how to adjust the canvas size by the total number of pixels, or based on a percentage, but neither of those seem to give me the results I need.

If it matters, a previous step in the process will be to scale the image by percentage (i.e. scale  to 75%, then add a 20px border).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `relative` box in the `Canvas size` dialog box:

[image]

Comment: After years of (admittedly light) Photoshop use, I can't believe that I never realized what that check-box meant!

Comment: ...and now you know. wisdom, years, you know the drill :)

Comment: Like ten years of Photoshop but never noticed that checkbox ;_;